# One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item status code: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I have made a table `Blog` with DynamoDB.

I want to insert the 2 parameters `title` and `content` in it which I am fetching from an HTML form.

The parameters `blogContent` and `blogTitle` seem to be valid when I print these 2 in the console.

But when I am inserting them in the table i get the error:

```
One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item
   status code: 400, request id: XXX"
```

```
type Item struct {
    id                 int
    content            string
    bodycontentversion string
    claps              int
    comments           int
    imageid            int
    title              string
    views              int
}


func awsblog() {

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )

    svc := dynamodb.New(sess)

    item := Item{
        id:                 1234,
        content:            blogContent,
        bodycontentversion: "abcd",
        claps:              5,
        comments:           10,
        imageid:            1234,
        title:              blogTitle,
        views:              10,
    }

    av, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(item)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got error marshalling new item:")
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    tableName := "Blog"

    input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        Item:      av,
        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
    }

    _, err = svc.PutItem(input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got error calling PutItem:")
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully updated '")
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the Primary Key of the table? It is likely that you are not including the primary key in `PutItem`, so the record cannot be created.

Comment: You are missing the key named 'id' in the item struct.

Comment: id is my primary key. I have made the changes you guys mentioned, still getting the same error. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Struct fields must be public in order for `MarshalMap` to do its magic.

Add a `fmt.Printf("marshalled struct: %+v", av)` to see the output of that function.

That will in turn require the DynamoDB fields to be capitalised, unless you add a `json:"field-name"` directive to the struct fields.

The result would be:

```
type Item struct {
    Id                 int    `json:"id"`
    Content            string `json:"content"`
    Bodycontentversion string `json:"bodycontentversion"`
    Claps              int    `json:"claps"`
    Comments           int    `json:"comments"`
    Imageid            int    `json:"imageid"`
    Title              string `json:"title"`
    Views              int    `json:"views"`
}
```

Comment: This is what a colleague of mine would call "unnatural acts".  This works but it is frustrating that languages use capitalization or lack-thereof as indicators for encapsulation visibility.

Comment: Go is opinionated by design, people tend to like it or hate it for that reason :)

Comment: Does the `MarshalMap` respect the json directive? The output I am seeing is still the capitals from the struct.

Comment: When using the [attributevalue package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue#pkg-overview) to Marshal the default key tag is ‘dynamodbav’. It wont read the json tag unless specifically told to do so.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error when putting an item with the boto3 Python package.

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item
```

The problem was that I did not specify the partition key correctly when inserting. I incorrectly specified PARTITION_KEY below. I misspelled the variable name (first line below), which caused the error which was not immediately visible from the error message.

```
PARTITION_KEY = 'hello'
SORT_KEY = 'world'

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
dynamodb.put_item(
    TableName=TABLE,
    Item={
        PARTITION_KEY: {'S': 'my-part-key'},
        SORT_KEY: {'S': 'my-sort-key'},
    }
)
```